# Loading encoded JSON into Dojo Grid

Tags: php, mysql, json, dojo

I am programming in php,
I want to take an `array` I have (which is extracted from mysql result set), convert it to `JSON` and then use it in `dojox.grid.DataGrid`.

I got an idea from [this link:](http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2011-June/056055.html)

I used the following on the `array` (in a file called `getJSON.php`)

```
echo $ajax = "{identifier: 'db_id', 'items':".json_encode($array)."}";
```

Then I try doing this (in my main page):

```
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ url: 'getJSON.php' });
```

Everything else is exactly as the Dojo documentation specifies.
The grid shows up, but doesn't load the data and instead writes `Sorry, an error occurred`

Does anyone know the reason? Hopefully I gave you enough to go on.

Comment: `{identifier:` is bad JSON.  Try `{"identifier"`  You can also try validating the full JSON if you have it with a tool like this: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: true, valid JSON also requires the exclusive use of douple-quotes (`"`)... But i guess this migth not be the issue here..

Comment: it seems to me as if sth. might be wrong with the way you create the grid. Did you provide a structure-definition? Maybe a bit of code might be helpful.. (especially the part where you create the grid the Grid)

Comment: the creation of the grid is taken from the link attached

Comment: just for the sake of argument..this: echo $ajax = '{\"identifier\": \"db_id\", \"items\":'.json_encode($result).'}'; doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't use ItemFileWriteStore for that ! They changed a lot since Dojo 1.6 , so maybe you looked at something not up to date.

Try this code:

> // Load the neccessary components (This is dojo with AMD ) !
>
> require(["dojo/aspect",'dojo/_base/lang',  'dojox/grid/DataGrid'
>   ,'dojo/dom' , 'dojo/store/JsonRest','dojo/data/ObjectStore',
>   'dojo/domReady!'],
>
> function(aspect,lang, DataGrid, dom,JsonRest,ObjectStore){ // Map components to vars...
>
> ```
> var store = new JsonRest({    
>       target: "getJSON.php" // Use a URL that you can open up in a browser.
>   });
>
>
> /*layout for the grid, you will have to adapt this to your columns !!!*/
> var layout = [[
>   {'name': 'Filename', 'field': 'documentName', 'width': '300px'},
>   {'name': 'Size', 'field': 'fileSize', 'width': '100px'},
>   {'name': 'Id', 'field': 'id', 'width': '200px'}
> ]];
>
> dataStore=ObjectStore({objectStore: store}); // Transform to Objectstore !
>
> /*Now we create a new grid*/
> var grid = new DataGrid({
>     id: 'grid',
>     store:dataStore, // Connect the store
>     autoWidth:false,
>     structure: layout, // Connect the layout
>     rowSelector: '0px'});
>
>
> grid.placeAt("yourTargetDivId"); // Has to be an existing DOM Element with id !
> grid.startup(); // START IT !
> ```
>
> });

Please try this code by echoing something simple like this first:

> echo '[{"id":"1","fileSize":"100kb","documentName":"Lucian !"},
>   {"id":"2","fileSize":"900kb","documentName":"Pew Pew !"}]';

And after that with your own JSON...