# Unable to access data in Dojo JsonRest store, target is PHP

Tags: php, json, dojo

I am trying to copy the results.total example from the dojotoolkit.org reference guide for dojo/Store/jsonRest (v1.8) [from here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/JsonRest.html).

My jsonRest store target is a php page [as I learned about here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803818/loading-encoded-json-into-dojo-grid), and I added  `console.debug(data);`  which in firebug shows that the data is returned from php the way I think it should be: (sorry tried to show pic here but I can't)

The problem is that I can’t figure out how to access the data?  `results.total.then` is returning nothing, I don’t think that function even gets run.

I tried `store.get` and that gives me a 404 error for the php url.  I tried converting the store like this: `newStore = ObjectStore({objectStore: store});` and then running a query on newStore, and this gives no error but also NO result.

I also get a 404 error if I try to query the store using the “foo=bar” syntax , in my case `store.query ("ADDNUM='200'")`  but there are no errors if I use the `store.query ({ADDNUM:"200"})` syntax.

My ultimate goal is to have the results show up in a dojo filteringselect, but for now I will settle for being able to get to them at all, even just console.log(result).
Very grateful for any help anyone can give!

```
require([
  "dojo/store/JsonRest", 
  "dojo/data/ObjectStore", 
  "dojo/store/Memory"
  ], function(JsonRest, Memory, ObjectStore){
    var store = new JsonRest({
    target: "scripts/AddressNumTest.php"
    });

var self = this;
var results = store.query({ADDNUM:"200"}).then(function(data){
  console.debug(data);  //results from this look okay to me
  results.total.then(function(total){
     console.log("Never gets here??");
     console.log("total results: ", total);
     console.log("go on and use data ", data, " with this ", self);
     });
  });

//store.query("ADDNUM='200'")  //this returns 404 error

//below gives 404 error           
//var results2 = store.get({ADDNUM:"200"}).then(function(newdata){
//console.log("from get: " + newdata);            
//});

});
```

`Result when no Error but also no success in accessing data in store:
GET ../scripts/AddressNumTest.php?ADDNUM=200  200 OK --
RESPONSE: {identifier: 'OBJECTID', label: 'ADDNUM', 'items':[{"ADDNUM":"136","OBJECTID":"307"},{"ADDNUM":"150","OBJECTID":"308"},{"ADDNUM":"200","OBJECTID":"8494"},{"ADDNUM":"210","OBJECTID":"8495"},{"ADDNUM":"220","OBJECTID":"2950"}]}`

`404 Error when using store.get:
GET .../scripts/AddressNumTest.php%5Bobject%20Object%5D 404 Not Found
RequestError: Unable to load scripts/AddressNumTest.php[object Object] status: 404`

`404 Error when I use "ADDNUM='200'" syntax:
GET .../scripts/AddressNumTest.phpADDNUM=%27200%27   404 Not Found
RequestError: Unable to load scripts/AddressNumTest.phpADDNUM='200' status: 404`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if results is available in the closure or not, but I don't think you need it.  The callback is passing in `data`, which looks correct to you in your `console.debug(data)`, so let me suggest this code.

```
var results = store.query({ADDNUM:"200"}).then(function(data){
  console.debug(data);  //results from this look okay to me
  console.log("You will get here!  :)");
  // I do not know what data looks like so this may or may not work.
  console.log("total results: ", data.total);
  console.log("go on and use data ", data, " with this ", self);
});
```

Comment: @uog let me know if this helps.  If you can't comment, you can edit the question.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I couldn't test it til now and still have some questions, but yes, `data` does hold the json returned from php. `data.total` comes back as undefined, but I don't actually need the total.  My filterselect never works so I wanted to be sure there really was something in the store.  Now I will go back to filterselect problem... Related question, maybe you know, since the query is for one specific value ("200"), why does `data` have _all_ the returned json?

Comment: Sorry I don't know why it is returning all rows.